# Use of unresolved identifier CNContact [swift 3]

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3, xcode8

In swift 2, this below line works

`var contacts = [CNContact]()`

But in swift 3 it's got 'Use of unresolved identifier CNContact' error message. I tried both insert and delete `import Contacts` since xcode 8 ignoring import because the viewcontroller is already part of module 'Contacts'. How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly working in `Swift 3.0`. I have just created a new project and I can freely use `CNContact`.

[image]

> Possible Workaround:

1. Delete Derived Data
2. Clean your project

Now try to build your project.

Comment: Where is the Derived Data placed?

Comment: @JavierHeisecke Here is the location: `/Users/Javier_PC_Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`